# Cannot migrate: relation does not exist (Django 2.1)

Tags: django

When I try to migrate, I get this error: "django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "TEST" does not exist". However, `TEST` is a postgresql table I no longer use. Right now, I have my `models.py` set to getting data from another table:

```
class cross_currents(models.Model):
    ArticleID = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'cross_currents'
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.Title}, {self.Author}, {self.Journal}, {self.Pub_Year}, {self.Issue}'
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('article-detail', args=[str(self.ArticleID)])
```

As you can see, my `db_table` is set to another table, not `TEST` (it was previously set to `TEST`), but `migrate` somehow keeps looking for `TEST`. Other than changing the value of `db_table`, what else do I need to do to tell Django that `TEST` is no longer used? When I `makemigrations` there is no issue.
Full traceback: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPcZZ.jpg

Comment: You likely have past migrations that reference `TEST`, and subsequent migrations depend on them. The solution depends on your specific case, but generally you can get out these situations by nuking your local database and existing migrations, then rerunning `makemigrations` to create a fresh, squashed migration based on the current state of your app without any references to `TEST`. Unless you have a really good reason for doing so, I suspect that by doing this you won't need to specify `db_table` anymore either.

Comment: @jpriebe thanks for the tip! May I ask how can I "nuke" my existing migrations?

Comment: delete every `.py` file except `__init__.py` inside migrations folder(don't delete the folder). Then drop your database, then create a database with same name. Then run `makemigrations` and `migrate`.

Comment: @VaibhavVishal thanks! deleting all the migration files solved the issue